# Does TFS 2013 have shelvesets anymore (when using GIT)?

Tags: git, version-control, visual-studio-2013, shelveset

I am having trouble finding any way to use shelvesets in Visual Studio 2013 using TFS.  Has that feature been removed, or is it not available when using a GIT repository?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This feature does not exist with a git repository. You need to use branches instead. This makes sense as a git branch is at the repository level, so they are functionally equivalent.